# JQuery loading script through ajax not working - only in firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to load addthis script through ajax but somehow it is not working only in firefox (Tried Developer + latest stable versions). It works fine in Chrome & Safari. Sample code is given below

```
initAddthis: function(){
  var that = this;
  var script = 'https://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-###';
  for (var i in window) {
    if (/^addthis/.test(i) || /^_at/.test(i)) {
      delete window[i];
    }
  }
  window.addthis_share = null;
  $.ajax({ url: script, 
         dataType: 'script', 
         cache: true
  }).done(function() {}).fail(function(jqhr, status, errorThrown){}); }
```

Also errorThrown doesn't have sufficient information. It just says 'error'. Not sure what's going on. I tried adding contentType: 'text/javascript' but still not working.

Comment: If possible can post response `headers` ? Thanks

Comment: 'TypeError: a is undefined' from the the returned jqxhr.getResponseHeader() method.

Comment: `a` not appear at OP ? Is variable `a` within other `js` ?